# I can't run relay this back to run "ans2"

Tags: python

i forgot how to run back different functions to connect to each other to run a simpler function

i cant run "ans2()" because i forgot the commands any help would be great

elif ans1 in answer_no:
print("\n you dont unlock yourself but you play dead instead while covering your mouth and a man with a gas mask comes over and you relize you need that gas mask take it? (Yes / No)\n")

```
ans3 = input(">>")

if ans3 in answer_yes:
```

run ans2():

Comment: that is very unclear what you try to do or problem you face. please [edit], fix code indentation and explain better

Comment: what do you mean by `run ans2` ?

Comment: Is `ans2` a function? Do you mean `ans2()`?